# Photoshop, how do I move a layer above the top group

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

In Photoshop, how is the most easy way to move a layer, which is inside a group, outside the group when the group is in top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the layers pallet, with the group expanded, click and hold on the layer, and move it up until the hand cursor it's over the line between the lock options/fill selector and the actual layers. There should be a thick line above the group, right at the top.

Release the mouse button.